# Why were these bad flags

Tags: support, flags

I flagged some posts yesterday, and two of them were apparently rejected, as no action was taken.  I would like to improve my flagging discrimination; please explain why these were bad flags:

---

[Reading feeds in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526768/reading-feeds-in-java)

"This is a discussion-type question, with no clear answer."

---

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525682/findrootremoveempty-files-on-unix

"off topic" (it seems to me this is a Unix shell question, not a programming question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No action does not mean they got rejected (as invalid flags), but sometimes moderators don't want to intervene in matters that can be solved by the community.

I know that's how we treat most of the flags on [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), we try to let the posts be closed by votes whenever possible.

Comment: When this is done, does it affect my flag weight?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It depends if they dismiss the flag as valid or invalid

Comment: @Michael is there a way to tell from the Flagging Summary that something was either rejected, or dismissed as invalid?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, but I wouldn't worry about it; just flag if you think you should

Answer (score 3):

The Java question is clearly a survey-type question. I voted to close.

The Unix question certainly doesn't seem like a programming question. I voted to migrate to SuperUser (although Unix.SE might work as well). EDIT: It was migrated at 23:07 UTC.

I'd say that both were decent flags.